# perl directory size not reporting the correct size

Tags: perl, directory, size

I need to determine the mail size to enforce quotas from perl.
When I do `du -bs /var/spool/mail/smith` from the command line I get a correct number.
But when I do the system command from perl (below) I always get 4096.
Selinux is not a factor.  There are no errors in the logs.

```
if ($mailboxSize = `du -bs /var/spool/mail/smith`) {
```

I don't think there is an equivalent command in perl to get a directory size, so how do I do it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the perl script running as the same user?  is the environment (specifically PATH) the same?

Comment: no ... I thought that might be the problem.  but I need to be able to check all users.

Comment: *as* the same user, not *on* the same user

Comment: well no ... I need this one program to be able to look at all users

Comment: yes, I know that.  but when you run it from the command line, you are logged in as some user; when you run it in the perl script, are you logged in as the same user?

Comment: command line runs as root ... perl program runs as defang (mimedefang user)

Comment: and when you run it from the command line logged in as defang, what happens?

Comment: defang does not have the power to login

Comment: as root, switch users to defang (`su defang`)

Comment: to rule out another possible class of problems, does `ls -id /var/spool/mail/smith` show the same number from the perl script and your root command line?

Comment: says "This account is currently not available." ... that user cannot log in

Comment: ls -id shows 16515158 ... and du -bs shows 1259879

Comment: no, I mean `ls -id ...` from the script *and* from the root command line, do they give the same value? it won't be at all the same as the du count you want.

Comment: yes ... ls -id does work! ... but the size is inodes ... how do I translate that to folder size in bytes?

Comment: you don't; just wanted to verify there wasn't something strange that was leading to the two different ways actually seeing different files.

Comment: is /var/spool/mail/smith a file or directory?  if a directory, it and any subdirectories will need to be readable and traversable (the x permission) by the defang user for du to work (though the files in it don't need to be readable).

Comment: ok then I'll have to try something else ... smith is a directory and defang does not have permissions.  so I'll have to sudo the du command but I was hoping to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

is /var/spool/mail/smith a file or directory? if a directory, it and any subdirectories will need to be readable and traversable (the x permission) by the defang user for du to work (though the files in it don't need to be readable). – ysth